# Android Kotlin: How to get Context for a Toast?

Tags: kotlin, toast

In my MainActivity I can use Toasts with application context "this".
I have two more activities, it does also work in the second, but not in the third.

The code Im trying to write it:

```
fun onButtonLogoutClicked(view: View){
        if (user != null){
            auth.signOut()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "there is no logged-in user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

So AndroidStudio tells me "'this' is not defined in this context.

I also googled and tried stuff like "getApplicationContext()" but AndroidStudio does not know this methods and I cannot import them.

Can anyone help (and explain me why "this" does not work?)?

Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Comment: Just use the context inside the view object `view.context`

Comment: You must be calling this from a place where `this` is ambiguous, like inside a lambda or listener.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to go about it.

```
fun onButtonLogoutClicked(view: View){
  if (user != null){
       auth.signOut()
  } else {
       Toast.makeText(this@MyActivity, "there is no logged-in user", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
  }
```

another is using the `context`.